# confusion on clock speed of ram ddr2 6400, is it 400 MHZ or 800 MHZ ?,I found both answers on web

Tags: laptop, memory, desktop-computer, ddr2, sdram

1-`DDR2-6400 is a designation used to indicate the peak bandwidth or data transfer rate of the memory module, not its clock speed.

The "6400" in DDR2-6400 represents the theoretical maximum data transfer rate in MB/s (megabytes per second) that the memory module can achieve. This is calculated by multiplying the module's data bus width (which for DDR2 is 64 bits) by the memory's clock speed, and then dividing by eight to convert bits to bytes.

To determine the clock speed of a DDR2-6400 module, we can rearrange the formula:

Data Transfer Rate (MB/s) = (Data Bus Width * Clock Speed) / 8

Given that DDR2 modules have a data bus width of 64 bits, and DDR2-6400 has a peak data transfer rate of 6400 MB/s, we can solve for the clock speed:

`6400 MB/s = (64 bits * Clock Speed) / 8

Solving for Clock Speed:

Clock Speed = (6400 MB/s * 8) / 64 bits Clock Speed = 800 MHz`

****Therefore, the clock speed of a DDR2-6400 module is 800 MHz.****

2-The term "DDR2-6400" typically refers to a DDR2 SDRAM (Double Data Rate 2 Synchronous Dynamic Random-Access Memory) module with a data transfer rate of 6400 MB/s (megabytes per second). However, the clock speed itself is half of this data transfer rate because DDR2 memory is capable of transmitting data twice per clock cycle (hence "double data rate").

To calculate the clock speed of a DDR2-6400 module, we need to divide the data transfer rate by the number of bits transmitted per data transfer and by 2 (since DDR2 is a double data rate memory type):

Data Transfer Rate = 6400 MB/s = 6400 * 8 Mb/s (converting megabytes to megabits) Clock Speed = Data Transfer Rate / (Number of Bits per Transfer * 2) For DDR2, each memory transfer involves a 64-bit data bus:  Clock Speed = (6400 * 8 Mb/s) / (64 bits/transfer * 2) clock speed = (6400 * 8) / 128 ****clock speed = 400 MHz****

**So, the clock speed of a DDR2-6400 module is 400 MHz. which one is the correct answer?**

Comment: I've always been told that DDR2-800 (PC2-6400) will have a total frequency of 800MHz when installed in a Dual-Channel array, but the per-channel frequency is half the label value (400MHz), so both channels can operate, each at 1/2 the speed of the frequency of the Data Bus.

Comment: If you copied and pasted all this information from a source you need to quote and cite it.

Answer (score 1):

The [DDR2 Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM) will give you a direct answer. I have highlighted one of the lines in the table below.

What you are missing in your calculations is that DDR makes two transfers per clock. While the "effective" clock (transfer rate) is 800MHz (MT/s), the actual clock is half that value. DDR is literally "Double Data Rate", hence two transfers per clock as opposed to the older RAM which only made one transfer per clock pulse.

DDR transfers data on both the rising and falling edges of the clock pulse as opposed to just the rising edge so as far as data rate is concerned it has the same rate as memory with twice the clock speed.

> | Standard | Type | Module | Clock rate (MHz) | Cycle time (ns)[6] | Clock rate (MHz) | Transfer rate (MT/s) | Bandwidth (MB/s) | CL-TRCD-TRP[7][8] | CAS latency (ns) |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | DDR2-1066 | D | PC2-8500* | 266 | 3.75 | 533 | 1066 | 8533 | 5-5-5 | 9.375 |
> | DDR2-1066 | E | PC2-8500* | 266 | 3.75 | 533 | 1066 | 8533 | 6-6-6 | 11.25 |
> | DDR2-1066 | F | PC2-8500* | 266 | 3.75 | 533 | 1066 | 8533 | 7-7-7 | 13.125 |
> | DDR2-800 | C | PC2-6400 | 200 | 5 | 400 | 800 | 6400 | 4-4-4 | 10 |
> | **DDR2-800** | **D** | **PC2-6400** | **200** | **5** | **400** | **800** | **6400** | **5-5-5** | **12.5** |
> | DDR2-800 | E | PC2-6400 | 200 | 5 | 400 | 800 | 6400 | 6-6-6 | 15 |
> | DDR2-667 | C | PC2-5300* | 166 | 6 | 333 | 667 | 5333 | 4-4-4 | 12 |
> | DDR2-667 | D | PC2-5300* | 166 | 6 | 333 | 667 | 5333 | 5-5-5 | 15 |
> | DDR2-533 | B | PC2-4200* | 133 | 7.5 | 266 | 533 | 4266 | 3-3-3 | 11.25 |
> | DDR2-533 | C | PC2-4200* | 133 | 7.5 | 266 | 533 | 4266 | 4-4-4 | 15 |
> | DDR2-400 | B | PC2-3200 | 100 | 10 | 200 | 400 | 3200 | 3-3-3 | 15 |
> | DDR2-400 | C | PC2-3200 | 100 | 10 | 200 | 400 | 3200 | 4-4-4 | 20 |